# Regex for only numbers in square brackets

Tags: regex

I want to check if all square brackets contain only numbers, commas, and dashes inside them. How to do that?

For example:

`fsf[sdff0977sf0]sda[989,-]`  not ok

`fsf[,,--9770-,875]sda[989,-]`  ok

Comment: which language are you running?

Comment: And did you try anything yourself?

Comment: java, I tryed something like this:.*\[[0-9[^0-9]]\].*
I am really new in this stuff so i have no good ideas

Comment: @roma, always a good idea to include your original code, even if it doesn't work, even if you are not quite sure what you're doing. Otherwise it looks like you haven't tried anything and are just using StackOverflow as a problem-solving/code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using. Here is a `grep` solution:

```
$ grep -Eo '\[([0-9]|,|-)+\]' file.txt 
[989,-]
[,,--9770-,875]
[989,-]
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use this pattern with the `matches` method:

```
[^\\[]*(?:\\[[0-9,-]*][^\\[]*)*+
```

that checks from start to end of the string if all parts in square brackets contains only digits, commas and hypens.

note: According to your requirements, the string and the content inside square brackets can be empty. However I assume that all opened square brackets are closed, and that square brackets are not nested.

[fiddle](http://fiddle.re/btuud6)

Comment: they are all closed and not nested

Answer (score 0):

I would also propose something very near to heemayl's answer. In JavaScript:

```
var pattern = /\[[0-9,-]+\]/g;
```

You can play around with it here : http://regexr.com/3ajek

Now, the only problem here is that in your example the first line should be detected as "not ok" because it contains a block of brackets with invalid data. As you can see on the regexr.com example above, it will not match. But the other block of brackets on that line will match. So if you want to validate all the line, you'll have to loop on each match of bracket blocks and then check that it contains valid data. If one of the bracket block doesn't contain valid data then all the line is invalid.

Not really sure to know what you are trying to validate as we haven't got the full context of your code.

Answer (score -1):

You might try something like this:

```
^(?!.*\[[^\]]*[^0-9\],-][^\]]*\])
```

[**See Regex 101 Demo here.**](https://regex101.com/r/bS0jP3/1)

Here I am asserting that the above pattern can't be found in the string. The above pattern is an opening square bracket `[` followed by any number of characters that are not closing square brackets `]`, followed by one character that is none of: number `0-9`, closing square bracket, comma, or dash, followed (again) by any number of characters that are not closing square brackets, followed by a closing square bracket.